# Java adjacency list

Tags: java, hash, matrix, adjacency-list

I am having trouble comprehending how to scan in an adjacency list to a graph. I understand how adjacency tables work and their mapping to each other but what I don't understand is what type of data type to store them in. My assignment is to take an input file that tells the number of vertexes G=(V,E) and gives the edges to the other numbers in the graph.

So for example:

```
3
010
101
110
```

so:

```
0 maps to 1
1 maps to 0
2 maps to 0
2 maps to 1
```

From there I have to implement a breath search and a depth search on them. Would a hash table be my best bet?

Answer (score 1):

The difference of using BFS and DFS is in which data structure you store the data, one is a "queue" the other is a "stack" (your answer). If you use a java list, you could get them from the beginning or from the end, but you can also use "real" stack and queue.

So in your case, create a List, and store the origin of your search in it.

After a while loop, while you have elements in your list keep it going.

So pick your element from the list ( first or last) and evaluate if it is your target, if it is not, store all its neighbors in the list and keep it going.

You may add something two stop adding the same element twice, you should have a list of visited nodes.

But, I have doubts if you wanted to know where to store the adjacency list. An array of lists would do. Every vertex, vertex[i] has a List with all the vertices that is connected to.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm doing it a different way now. I'm just gotta use a stack and queue like you said. Thanks a lot man!!!